# Using getParameterValues and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

So I getting parameters from another page, and putting them into an array, I am then taking all items in that array and running the `substring` method on them:

```
String[] edit = request.getParameterValues("editID");
// System.out.println(edit);
String editDel = "";
  if (edit != null) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < edit.length; ++i) {
        String lf = edit[i];
        editDel = lf.substring(0, lf.length() - 2);  
  } } else { editDel = "0"; }
// System.out.println(editDel);
```

So for example if I pass the params `3lf` and `12lf` from my previous page, the system prints `[Ljava.lang.String;@520` for the variable `edit`, and prints `12` for the variable `editDel`.  Do i need to store `editDel` in an array, because I should be getting both `12` and `3` for the `editDel` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the editDel print statement inside the for loop

```
   for (int i = 0; i < edit.length; ++i) {
    String lf = edit[i];
    editDel = lf.substring(0, lf.length() - 2);  
    System.out.println(editDel);
    } } else { editDel = "0"; }
```

Comment: this does work for when I am printing it out, but I need to extend the use of the editDel variable to other parts of my page.   Anything I can do on that front?

Comment: editDel is a variable that can hold only one value. If you want both values, then you must continue to use the array. If you want the array to contain substrings instead of the original strings, just replace them by using "edit[i] = lf.substring(0, lf.length() - 2);"